# Recognizing bees in a beehive

Tags: object-recognition

I would like to know if image recognition software would be sophisticated enough to recognize reach single bee in a bee hive separately (for the purpose of tracking it, and tracking, and accounting, of its social interactions).

What would be involved at the hardware and software level.

I think this could be very important, and interesting, for people who maintain beehives (they could have special IoT beehives made where they could install side panes next to where the bees deposited honey to track them, and hopefully fall in love with them).

What are the parameters that would affect any given considerations in developing such a system, and what are some of the challenges that could be encountered in developing such a system and making it work?

Thanks.

Comment: You could read some papers.  I searched on "machine recognizing individual bees in a hive" and got [this paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/frobt.2018.00035/full), it has references and I saw some phrases that look like they have much better search terms.  The authors talked a lot about marked bees, which is certainly a way of answering "how can I recognize an individual bee in a hive?".  Expect to spend a man-day or two before you even know you're on the right track -- and if you find something definitive, please come back and answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Optical Challenges

I assume that to be hard, physically. At any given time, most bees in a hive are sisters – the sperm of the few drones that the queen mated with is gone through more or less in "packets". So, the bees are genetically pretty similar, and since the life cycles also mean that bees fulfilling the same role are of similar age and hence were raised under similar conditions, the environmentally caused differentiation isn't too pronounced.

So, maybe you want to talk to a bee biologist first about this (I know Uni Hohenheim has a nice department for Melittology), and figure out what the visual differences are – I doubt too many of us here know it! Armed with that domain knowledge (and maybe even pictures) you could ask here more detailledly!

## Technological Challenges

Mounting a camera in a hive will be hard. Bees plaster everything with wax. And I mean everything.

> Where the bees deposit honey

That's in the combs, which are plates that need to be mounted parallel with little space in between them (otherwise the bees will build "bridges" between them, which makes the honeycombs impossible to harvest for honey), so I don't think there's an option to point a camera at them.

## Meaning

> And hopefully fall in love with them

I don't want to ruin the romanticism, but bee love is very procreationally focused and only executed on a once-in-a-lifetime basis. Also, providing genetic material is literally the only purpose of the male bees, they can't even defend themselves, so they die soon after mating.

If you mean the beekeeper: Well, they're already taking care of bees! No need for them to fall any more in love.

If you mean the general public: Hm, there's 50000 bees in a hive. You won't see much of a single bee in its honey-gathering stadium. It's going to be at rest (nighttime, very bad weather) or gathering (daytime).

### Importance

Being able to recognize leaving and returning bees at the hive entry would still be scientifically important. So, it really pays to talk to a bee scientist: they will know what is currently possible, and how they track how long bees are out, for example. Be polite when asking for their time - zoology is one of the fields that requires a lot of personal time spent with the subjects, and hence, slicing off a bit of time to discuss things with you will often come out of afterhours :) Still, most Mettologists I've talked to are very nice!